# Storing job-specific data

Tags: multithreading, playframework, threadpool, playframework-1.x

In my play application I have several Jobs and I have a singleton class.

What I would like to do is for each Job to store data in the singleton class and I would like to be able to retrieve from this singleton class the data that corresponds to the current Job via yet another class.

In other words I would like to have something like this:

*-Job 1 stores "Job1Data" in the singleton class*

*-Job 2 stores "Job2Data" in the singleton class*

*-Another class asks the singleton class data for the currently executing job (in the current thread I guess) and use it*

To perform this I assumed each Job is run on a different thread. Then what I did is that data from each Job stored in the singleton class is stored in a Map that maps the current thread id with the data.

However I'm not sure this is the way I should do it because it may not be thread safe (although Hashtable is said to be thread-safe) and maybe another thread is created each time the Job is executed which would make my Map grow a lot and never clear it-self.

I thought of another way to do what I want. Maybe I could use the ThreadLocal class in my singleton to be sure it's thread-safe and that I store thread-specific data. However I don't know if it will work well if another thread is used each time a Job is executing. Furthermore, I read somewhere that ThreadLocal creates memory leaks if the data is not remove, and the problem is that I don't know when I can remove the data.

So, would anybody have a solution for my issue ? I would like to be sure data I would like to store during Job execution is stored in a global class and can be accessed by another class (with an access to the data of the correct Job, thus the correct thread I guess).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Couldn't you use Play's own Cache for this? Although it's not _guaranteed_ to return the result, I think it would easily be just as reliable store as any other memory-based implementation. And if you _really_ want to be sure data gets stored, why don't you use a database? Anyways, this sounds like a problem where ready-made solutions are plentiful - so it's probably not worth it to implement your own.

Comment: @Tom Actually I finally used ThreadLocal. This way I can store my Job data for each thread an there is no concurrency problem. By the way Play's jobs use a thread pool ? That means the number of threads is limited and they will never change ? (always same id, etc...)